# What do different values of $y$ mean when we plot different graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

When solving an equation such as $x^2 = 9$ we write $x = 3$ $or$ $x = -3$. Now take the functions $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 4$ for all $x$. When we plot them on the $xy$ plane we write $y=2x$ and $y=4$. If we were to evaluate them at $x=1$ we have $y=2$ for the first one, and $y=4$ for the second one. Now I would like to ask, is the correct way to write this, $y=2$ $and$ $y=4$, or is it, $y=2$  $or$ $y=4$? I am uncomfortable with saying $y=2$ and $y=4$ as this implies $2=4$ I think.

Comment: For two linear equations of two variables: $y=2x$ and $y=4$ there is only one solution that should be written as $x=2, y=4$ or write $x=2$ and $y=4$

Comment: I am not talking about solving their intersection.

Comment: If there are more than two solutions use 'OR'

Comment: When $x=1$, your AND of the two equations ($y=2x,y=4$) is equivalent to $y=2$ AND $y=4$ (i.e. to FALSE if the domain is $\Bbb R$ e.g.).

Comment: How can I use AND does that not imply $2=4$? Also for you Anne Bauval,  when we write $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ to draw $f$ and $g$ on the coordinate plane, we should really say OR rather than AND, as AND implies we want their intersection only?

Comment: See my updated previous comment. But I think you should edit your question to clarify it. I.e. to tell us whether your initial system of2 equations is an AND or an OR

Comment: The initial system is just two graphs on the $xy$ plane, I myself am asking the question is that an AND or OR case, and I think that its AND case when we want their intersection, OR everywhere else.

Comment: As for drawing graphs of functions, that is a distinct question from writing and solving a system of equations. Your post is not clear. I think you should rewrite it completely.

Comment: I am merely asking how we get around the fact that $y$ is usually written down twice. How can we have $y$ equal to two different values at once? Is it an OR case?

Comment: I have rewritten my post/

Comment: Now I fully agree with you: for two simultaneous plots it is an OR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same $xy$-plane, if you plot $y=2x$, *and* also plot $y=4$, then:

$$\text{the point $(x,y)$ is marked} \iff (y=2x \text{ or } y=4)$$

If you find the intersection of the marked points with "the points where $x=1$", then there are only two points in the intersection:

$$\begin{align*}
((\text{the point $(x,y)$ is marked}) \text{ and } x=1)
&\iff ((y=2x\text{ or } y=4)\text{ and } x=1)\\
&\iff ((y=2\text{ or } y=4)\text{ and } x=1)\\
&\implies (y=2\text{ or } y=4)
\end{align*}$$

---

I find this usage of "and","or" in English analogous to:

- I bought an apple *and*  I bought an orange.
- There's an apple *and* an orange in my shopping bag.
- If I pick a fruit out of my shopping bag, the fruit is either an apple *or* an orange.

Comment: So it is an OR, thanks for your answer I will mark it as solution as IMO its the most clear, but I am thankful for everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 3):

Using the same variable $y$ in the two equations is ambiguous. The statement
$$
y = 2x \text{ and } y = 4
$$
implies
$$
x = 2
$$
while the statement
$$
(y = 2x \text{ or } y = 4) \text{ and } x = 1
$$
implies
$$
y = 2 \text{ or } y = 4
$$

**Edit** to include this comment from @FilipMilovanović

> As for $x^2=9$, you can think of it as $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=9$ - the
> reason there is an "or" used to describe the solutions is because
> these two graphs intersect at two places. In general there can be more
> than 2 solutions, or none.

Comment: So when we write $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ to draw $f$ and $g$ on the coordinate plane, we should really say OR rather than AND, as AND implies we want their intersection only?

Comment: To draw both you  just have two graphs on the same set of axes. To see where they cross you want to know the values of $x$ for which $f(x) = g(x)$. In both cases you are better off saying what you mean in words rather than making $y$ do double duty and fussing with "and" or "or".

Comment: If you had to draw $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 4$ on same coordinate grid, would you not write $y=2x$ and $y=4$?

Comment: @James - "we should really say OR rather than AND, as AND implies we want their intersection only" - no, there is no AND nor OR in the solution for your "$f(x)=2x$ and $g(x) = 4$". We *do* want their intersection only - the intersection is the point where $f(x)=2x$ is true *and* $g(x) = 4$ is true, which is what we're implicitly looking for. As for $x^2 = 9$, you can think of it as $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 9$ - the reason there is an "or" used to describe the solutions is because these two graphs intersect at *two* places. In general there can be more than 2 solutions, or none.

Comment: @ryang Yes thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Now take the functions $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = 4$ for all $x$. When we plot them on the $xy$-plane we write $y=2x$ and $y=4.$

Clearer to write $\text“y_1=2x$ and $y_2=4\text”,$ that is, $y_1=f(x)$ and $y_2=g(x).$

> I would like to ask, is the correct way to write $\quad y=2$ $and$ $y=4,$
>
> or is it $\quad y=2$  $or$ $y=4$?

The former implies that $\text“y\text”$ is non-existent, while the latter implies that $\text“y\text”$ has no more than two possible values. (Notice that in fact $y_1$ has infinitely many possible values, one for each value of $x.$) Neither is quite what you want.

---

**Reply to the OP's comment**

> I always see $y$
> used twice, is this lazy notation or mathematically wrong? Must we use $y_1$
> and $y_2$
> ? If we use OR then its clear that $y$
> has two possible values for each $x$
> . (And the value we chose to look at is dependant on us looking at either $f$
> or $g.$)

I don't know that it is wrong, but it is tacit that these two copies of $y$ have separate contexts, representing the vertical coordinates of separate curves. Say, we are investigating in the science lab how three variables S, N and H depend on the independent variable V; in isolation, you could call each of the three dependent variables $y,$ but while discussing them collectively you'd obviously call them $y_1,$ $y_2,$ $y_3$ (else: S, N, H) instead. $\quad$ In short, recycling the label $\text“y\text”$ is conflating separate contexts.

Comment: I always see $y$ used twice, is this lazy notation or mathematically wrong? Must we use $y_1$ and $y_2$? If we use OR then its clear that $y$ has two possible values for each $x$. (And the value we chose to look at is dependant on us looking at either $f$ or $g$)

Comment: @James Please also see this [related comment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/why-is-absolute-value-difficult/26229#comment69039_26229).

Comment: Yeah Ryan I agree with your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An equation (implicitly) describes a collection of points. When you write $y=2x$ you are actually writing
\begin{align}
\text{all points $(x,y)$ for which $y=2x$ holds true}
\end{align}
In set builder notation this looks as follows
$$\left\{(x,y)\mid y=2x\right\}$$
where you should read the vertical bar as "such that".

When you write two equations you implicitly require *two* equations to hold true at the same time. You will generally loose points in this process. This process is also called the "intersection" of these two equations. This name might be more obvious if you draw a Venn diagram

[image]

The blue circle describes all points for which $A$ holds true. The red circle describes all points for which $B$ holds true. If you write them both down as a system of equations you will get the intersection $A\cap B$, or the middle part in the Venn diagram. You will loose all the points that are outside this intersection.

Let's try to write an example in set builder notation. We have the system of equations
$$\cases{y=x^2-8\\y=2x}$$
In set builder notation this becomes

\begin{align}
&\left\{(x,y)\mid y=x^2-8\text{ and }y=2x\right\}=\\
&\left\{(x,y)\mid x^2-8=2x\text{ and }y=2x\right\}=\\
&\left\{(x,y)\mid x^2-2x-8=0\text{ and }y=2x\right\}=\\
&\left\{(x,y)\mid (x+2)(x-4)=0\text{ and }y=2x\right\}=\\
&\left\{(x,y)\mid (x=-2\text{ or }x=4)\text{ and }y=2x\right\}=\\
&\left\{(x,y)\mid (x=-2 \text{ and }y=-4)\text{ or }(x=4\text{ and }y=8)\right\}=\\
&\left\{(-2,-4),(4,8)\right\}\\
\end{align}
So our final answer is a set containing two points: $(-2,-4)$ and $(4,8)$. Actually, each step in this derivation is the same set of two points. You can check this by plotting every equation that is joined by an "and" an seeing that the two equations intersect in precisely those two points. I should note that wherever you see "or" you are performing a *union* operation. A union operation creates a larger set. For example the union of $\{1,2,5\}$ and $\{5,6\}$ is $\{1,2,5,6\}$. It "adds" the sets together but without allowing duplicates.

Now to get to your specific question. You were basically asking what happens if you have the following system of equations
\begin{align}
y&=2x\\
y&=4\\
x&=1
\end{align}
If you plot these you will find that there is no point where all these equations are true at the same time. The intersection of these equations is empty. The answer is the empty set $\{\}$ containing *no* points.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

Let's go back to the basic definition of AND and OR. $P$ AND $Q$ means *both* $P$ and $Q$ are true. $P$ OR $Q$ means *one* of them is true. (In the context of computer science, OR means *at least one* is true, but in the context of mathematics, OR is usually used to imply only one of them is true)

In your example, writing "$y=2$ AND $y=4$" will mean both $y=2$ and $y=4$ are true, which implies $2=4$ as you have said. Writing "$y=2$ OR $y=4$" won't be appropriate either. In this case, you have to specify which functions you are referring to. The correct form will be "$f(x)=2$ AND $g(x)=4$ when $x=1$", because both the statements "$f(x)=2$ when $x=1$" and "$g(x)=4$ when $x=1$" are correct.

Comment: How would you write the solutions to $x^2 = 9$? I would put $x=-3$ or $x=3$ to mean that yes, both of them are solutions, but no, $x$ cannot be both at once. Is it not the same case here with $y$. From reading your comment I think you would put and, because both are true, but even then, how can $x$ be two things at once....

Comment: You can write "**the solutions are** $x=-3$ **AND** $x=3$", but you must write "$x=-3$ **OR** $x=3$".

Comment: Alright, thanks. How does this work when we write $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, in your case you did not use $y$ at all (perhaps on purpose?), but instead opted for the function notation.

Comment: As @EthanBolker has already mentioned, using the same variable $y$ in different and unrelated equations is ambiguous.

Comment: So writing $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ is just sloppy notation at the end of the day? (Or do these statements mean something completely different....)

Comment: Well I won't say sloppy, but letting $y=f(x)$ and then saying $y=2$ at $x=1$ is redundant. Saying $f(x)=2$ at $x=1$ is much clearer and simpler.

Comment: Using $f(x)$ > Using $y$!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit more nuanced than "OR vs AND".

From a practical software perspective, when you plot two curves you want to distinguish them in some way. So if you plot f(x) red and g(x) green, then the appropriate relation is:

```
if y == f(x)
then Color(x, y) == Red
else
  if y == g(x)
  then Color(x, y) == Green
  else Color(x, y) == Transparent
```

where you can read `if A then B else C` as a shorthand for `(NOT A OR B) AND (A OR C)`.

In contrast, if you use the relation `y == f(x) OR y == g(x)`, then the curves will share the same color (the *union* of two curves). Correspondingly, *AND* would translate to the *intersection*.

Comment: Take DESMOS as a pretty example, we plot the graphs with different colours (OR) then we use AND to describe their intersections.